# How to remove the corresponding value in three list that is duplicated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have three list that is like:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 0, 3, 5, 0, 1]
c = [0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.44, 0.6, 0.9, 0.3, 0.77]
```

With a correspond to b, the first value in `a` and `b` is `0,1`, which equals to the fourth value in `a` and `b` `1,0` and I want to remove it in `a,b,c` to get a list:

```
aa:[0,0,0,1,2,2,3]
bb:[1,2,3,9,3,5,1]
cc:[0.1,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.6,0.9,0.77]
```

And I tried to use remove:

```
for i,u in enumerate(a):
   if a[i] == b[i] and b[i] == a[i]:
      a.remove(a[i])
      b.remove(b[i])
      c.remove(c[i])
```

And it didn't work. Can anyone let me know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your lists and build up a selectors list, e.g.:

```
seen = set()
selectors = []
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    if (x, y) in seen:
        selectors.append(0)
        continue
    seen.add((y, x))
    selectors.append(1)
```

Note: if the order doesn't matter (i.e. exclude `(1, 0)` and `(0, 1)`) then you can use `frozenset(x, y)` instead of tuples in the `seen` set.

Now you can use these `selectors` with `itertools.compress()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
import itertools as it
list(it.compress(c, selectors))

Out[]:
[0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.9, 0.77]
```

To get your final variables:

```
aa = list(it.compress(a, selectors))  # [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]
bb = list(it.compress(b, selectors))  # [1, 2, 3, 9, 3, 5, 1]
cc = list(it.compress(c, selectors))  # [0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.9, 0.77]
```

Or more succinctly:

```
aa, bb, cc = [list(it.compress(lst, selectors)) for lst in (a, b, c)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the code below will do the job.

```
removed_indices = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
        if j in removed_indices:
            continue
        if a[i] == b[j] and b[i] == a[j]:
            removed_indices.append(j)
for i in reversed(removed_indices):
    a.pop(i)
    b.pop(i)
    c.pop(i)
```

It first finds positions of repetitive items (j in the second for loop) and if it hasn't been removed already, will add it to a list (removed_indices). Finally, the code removes items backward (in order to maintain the order of positions).

Answer (score 0):

A solution , you build a new list NewA,NewB,NewC , by copying each  tuple .
But before copying , you check if the tuple already exist .

```
NewA = []
NewB = []
NewC = []

for i,u in enumerate(a):
    found=0
    for j,v in enumerate(NewA):
        if a[i] == NewB[j] and b[i] == NewA[j] :
        found=1
    if found == 0 :
        NewA.append(a[i])
        NewB.append(b[i])
        NewC.append(c[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because no one had mentioned `frozenset` yet:

```
In [1]: a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
   ...: b = [1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 0, 3, 5, 0, 1]
   ...: c = [0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.44, 0.6, 0.9, 0.3, 0.77]

In [2]: seen = set()
   ...: to_del = []
   ...: for i, n in enumerate(a):
   ...:     pair = frozenset((n, b[i]))
   ...:     if pair in seen:
   ...:         to_del.append(i)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         seen.add(pair)
   ...:
   ...: for i in reversed(to_del):
   ...:     del a[i]
   ...:     del b[i]
   ...:     del c[i]
   ...:

In [3]: a
Out[3]: [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]

In [4]: b
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 9, 3, 5, 1]

In [5]: c
Out[6]: [0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.9, 0.77]
```

Or, if you want to create a new copy of `a`, `b`, and `c` and leave the original lists intact:

```
In [2]: aa, bb, cc = [], [], []
   ...: seen = set()
   ...: for i, n in enumerate(a):
   ...:     pair = frozenset((n, b[i]))
   ...:     if pair not in seen:
   ...:         seen.add(pair)
   ...:         aa.append(n)
   ...:         bb.append(b[i])
   ...:         cc.append(c[i])
   ...:

In [3]: aa
Out[3]: [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]

In [4]: bb
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 9, 3, 5, 1]

In [5]: cc
Out[5]: [0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.9, 0.77]
```

Comment: You may find that I did mention `frozenset()` and when to use it :). Note: An alternative is to `zip()` the lists which avoids the need to index into the other lists.